# Find the sides of a triangle

Tags: vectors

[image]

In this question I am just getting that all the three vectors should be coplanar as the sum of their coefficients is zero .

After that I am stuck , can anybody provide me hint?

Comment: it must be $$200x=150y$$,$$150y=120z$$,$$120z=200x$$ since the vectors are linear independend

Comment: Next time, please use this [_MathJax tutorial_](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner this can be true only when they are zero

Comment: 1. Show how you attempted to solve the problem. This way others will respond and no one will downvote your post.

Comment: 2. Use mathjax code to write your formulas. Do not send pictures, sometimes its hard to read.

Comment: but the right-hand side of this equation must be $$\vec{0}$$

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: @Théophile this was given by my institute

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner to satisfy linear dependent vector x=y=z=0 . Am I correct .

Comment: ti think so but you get no triangle in this case

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can we say x ,y and z are modulus of complex numbers X,Yand Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The vectors ${\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2$, and ${\bf v}_1 \times {\bf v}_2$ are linearly independent. Therefore, if $a{\bf v}_1 + b{\bf v}_2 + c({\bf v}_1 \times {\bf v}_2) = 0$, then $a=b=c=0$; you can thus get a relationship between $x,y$, and $z$, namely, $(x,y,z) = (3t,4t,5t)$ for some $t$.

In other words, $XYZ$ is similar to a $(3,4,5)$ triangle...

Comment: Actually the answer of this question is option A ,B ,C and D

Comment: @search This is why context is important! You provided no instructions for the question, so it looks like standard multiple choice in which one of the four answers is right. It's strategic to narrow down the choices in such cases, so I stopped after finding one right answer.

Comment: I am extremely Sorry , this will not happen again .

Comment: @search I added a bit more information. Does this give you enough to see that all four answers are right?